# Spring Roo Tomcat issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am facing a really annoying issue with Spring Roo and Tomcat.
Following the spring roo pizza shop tutorial I have issued the following commands:

```
project com.springsource.pizzashop

// Setup JPA persistence using EclipseLink and H2
jpa setup --provider ECLIPSELINK --database H2_IN_MEMORY

// Create domain entities
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Base --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --sizeMin 2 --notNull

entity jpa --class ~.domain.Topping --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --sizeMin 2 --notNull

entity jpa --class ~.domain.Pizza --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2
field number --fieldName price --type java.math.BigDecimal
field set --fieldName toppings --type ~.domain.Topping
field reference --fieldName base --type ~.domain.Base

entity jpa --class ~.domain.PizzaOrder --testAutomatically --identifierType ~.domain.PizzaOrderPk
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 2
field string --fieldName address --sizeMax 30
field number --fieldName total --type java.math.BigDecimal
field date --fieldName deliveryDate --type java.util.Date
field set --fieldName pizzas --type ~.domain.Pizza

field string --fieldName shopCountry --class ~.domain.PizzaOrderPk
field string --fieldName shopCity
field string --fieldName shopName

// Offer JSON remoting for all domain types trough Spring MVC
json all --deepSerialize
web mvc json setup
web mvc json all

web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
```

Then from the command line I call:

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

When I add a new field in the Pizza entity I get the error:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [pizza] in context with path [/pizza] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx'.] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label_com_springsource_pizzashop_domain_pizza_newfield' for locale 'el_GR'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.input_tagx._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(input_tagx.java:661)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.input_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f3(input_tagx.java:584)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.input_tagx.doTag(input_tagx.java:338)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx._jspx_meth_field_005finput_005f6(create_jspx.java:329)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx.access(create_jspx.java:310)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx$Helper.invoke0(create_jspx.java:385)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx$Helper.invoke(create_jspx.java:402)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.create_tagx$Helper.invoke0(create_tagx.java:697)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.create_tagx$Helper.invoke(create_tagx.java:738)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(panel_tagx.java:193)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx.doTag(panel_tagx.java:139)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.create_tagx.doTag(create_tagx.java:242)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx._jspx_meth_form_005fcreate_005f0(create_jspx.java:109)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pizzas.create_jspx._jspService(create_jspx.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:233)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Edit:** Just a bit of clarification. When I stop the server and start it again, everything is normal and the field is normally added. I have tried to add the field with roo commands and by modifying the java code.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Error is pretty clear: `No message found under code 'label_com_springsource_pizzashop_domain_pizza_newfield' for locale 'el_GR'`

Answer (score 1):

As Xaerxess suggested: In your `application.properties` (should be in `project-root/src/main/WEB-INF/i18n/`) is missing the line

```
label_com_springsource_pizzashop_domain_pizza_newfield=Label for newfield
```

Those labels are generated for generated entity fields at least if you use the web mvc Spring Roo module (can't speak for web json though), although in my current project only for the default locale (might be a configuration mistake at project start).

Somewhat mysterious is that your code does not show the generation of a field `newfield`. Did you manually introduce this field in your entity?

Comment: Do you mean that the entry in `application.properties` is correctly added by Spring Roo but is only read after a Tomcat restart? In my experience, the i18n properties files are only reloaded when Tomcat is restarted. Here is a [thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113590-Reload-property-file-without-restarting-tomcat) on reloading without restarting.